# How to use 800.000 years BC in Postgres and Apache Superset

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp, apache-superset

I have the impression this is a no-solution question... I want to display a graph via Postgres and Apache Superset with data 800.000 years back in time. The data ist in a CSV file, which I would like to upload, either in an existing Postgres database or whatever option Apache Superset is offering.

Now, [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html) offers only these date/timestamp options, it seems:

[image: postgres date time]

where date and timestamp can not be used for my purposes. Interval does neither seem to be an option, as there are no same-distance intervals between the data points; but I have never used the interval option before, so no sure how that one would work.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: You apparently only want years, not a full date (including month and day), so why not simply use an integer column that stores the amount of years? Negative for BC and positive for AD

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thx! The thing is, that Apache Supersets requires the date to be a date... However, I found a way around... Will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Apache Superset in principle requires the »date« field to be date, on can force it to consider a for example integer field as »temporal«. So, the combination of »integer« in the database and »temporal« in Superset makes it possible to display -800.000 years.